# is it possible i create post and also want to redirect on same post after creation in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
DB::table('job_post')->insert(['user_id'=>$user->id,'job_title'=>$data['job_title'],'job_skill'=>$data['skill'],'max_sal'=>$data['max_sal'],'min_sal'=>$data['min_sal'],'job_type'=>$data['job_type'],'shift'=>$data['shift'],'last_date'=>$data['last_date'],'job_image'=>$imagename,'job_description'=>$data['job_description'],'latitude'=>$data['latitude'],'longitude'=>$data['longitude'],'location'=>$data['location']]);
            //return redirect()->to('employer/congrats/......here i want id of job_post which i create');
            return view('employer/congrats',compact('id','navbar_data'));
```

Comment: Yes. it is possible

Comment: Show your routes as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You Can Get last inserted id in Laravel by insertGetId:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    array('email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0)
);

return redirect('employer/congrats',compact('id','navbar_data'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
$id = DB::table('job_post')->insertGetId([
    // ... data to insert e.g. 'user_id' => $user->id,
]);

return view('employer.congrats', compact('id','navbar_data'));
```

or

```
DB::table('job_post')->insert([
    // ... data to insert e.g. 'user_id' => $user->id,
]);
$id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

return view('employer.congrats', compact('id','navbar_data'));
```

For more, check out [this](https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-get-last-inserted-id-with-example) blog post.